# Batch File - getting yesterdays date and applying in current batch file

Tags: batch-file

First off i am very new to batch files but here is what i need to do.
i need to change IE's Homepage every day, but i need to get yesterdays date and apply it to the web address. example...

this is what i have currently.

```
@echo off
REG DELETE "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main" /v "Start Page" /f
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main" /v "Start Page" /d "http://ibapps.ibank.local/Reports/address-discrepancy-report-02.17.2015.html" /f
```

What needs to happen is to get yesterdays date and put it in where the date is on the web address.. ie 02.17.2015
any help would be much appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal

Call :GetDateTime Year Month Day
Echo %Year% %Month% %Day%
Call :SubtractDate %Year% %Month% %Day% -1 Ret
echo %Ret%
    REG DELETE "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet  Explorer\Main" /v "Start Page" /f
    REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main" /v "Start Page" /d "http://ibapps.ibank.local/Reports/address-discrepancy-report-%ret%.html" /f
exit /b


:SubtractDate Year Month Day <+/-Days> Ret
::Adapted from DosTips Functions::
setlocal & set a=%4
set "yy=%~1"&set "mm=%~2"&set "dd=%~3"
set /a "yy=10000%yy% %%10000,mm=100%mm% %% 100,dd=100%dd% %% 100"
if %yy% LSS 100 set /a yy+=2000 &rem Adds 2000 to two digit years
set /a JD=dd-32075+1461*(yy+4800+(mm-14)/12)/4+367*(mm-2-(mm-14)/12*12)/12-3*((yy+4900+(mm-14)/12)/100)/4
if %a:~0,1% equ + (set /a JD=%JD%+%a:~1%) else set /a JD=%JD%-%a:~1%
set /a L= %JD%+68569,     N= 4*L/146097, L= L-(146097*N+3)/4, I= 4000*(L+1)/1461001
set /a L= L-1461*I/4+31, J= 80*L/2447,  K= L-2447*J/80,      L= J/11
set /a J= J+2-12*L,      I= 100*(N-49)+I+L
set /a YYYY= I, MM=100+J, DD=100+K
set MM=%MM:~-2% & set DD=%DD:~-2%
set ret=%MM: =%.%DD: =%.%YYYY: =%
endlocal & set %~5=%ret%
exit /b

:GetDateTime Year Month Day Hour Minute Second
@echo off & setlocal
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%" & set "Min=%dt:~10,2%" & set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"
( ENDLOCAL
     IF "%~1" NEQ "" set "%~1=%YYYY%" 
     IF "%~2" NEQ "" set "%~2=%MM%" 
     IF "%~3" NEQ "" set "%~3=%DD%"
     IF "%~4" NEQ "" set "%~4=%HH%" 
     IF "%~5" NEQ "" set "%~5=%Min%"
     IF "%~6" NEQ "" set "%~6=%Sec%"
)
exit /b
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a .bat/jscript hybrid and should be saved with .bat extension.

```
@if (@X)==(@Y) @end /* JScript comment
    @echo off

    rem :: the first argument is the script name as it will be used for proper help message
    for /f %%$ in ('cscript //E:JScript //nologo "%~f0"') do set "yesterday=%%$" 

    REG DELETE "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main" /v "Start Page" /f
    REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main" /v "Start Page" /d "http://ibapps.ibank.local/Reports/address-discrepancy-report-%yesterday%.html" /f

    exit /b %errorlevel%



@if (@X)==(@Y) @end JScript comment */

$today = new Date();
$yesterday = new Date($today);
$yesterday.setDate($today.getDate() - 1);
var $dd = $yesterday.getDate();
var $mm = $yesterday.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!

var $yyyy = $yesterday.getFullYear();
if($dd<10){$dd='0'+dd} if($mm<10){$mm='0'+$mm} $yesterday = $dd+'.'+$mm+'.'+$yyyy;

WScript.Echo($yesterday);
```