# How to get Current Date - 1, -2 ,-3 , -4 in Batch

Tags: date, batch-file, batch-processing

This is what i would like to do:

1. Get Current Date,  which is easy --- %DATE%
2. DO Current Date - 1, which i cant seem to get as i have tried different options.

I would like to get last 4 dates from the current date and then store them in 4 different variables. Then Convert each of these date into YYYYMMDD format.

So %DATE% gives me 06/04/2016.....
%DATE%

```
-1 should give me 05/04/2016 stored in Variable say Date1........
-2 should give me 04/04/2016 stored in Variable say Date2........
-3 should give me 03/04/2016 stored in Variable say Date3........
-4 should give me 02/04/2016 stored in Variable say Date4........
```

then i would like to convert value stored in each of these variables into YYYYMMDD

For ex:

```
05/04/2016 to 20160405 ....
04/04/2016 to 20160404 ....
03/04/2016 to 20160403 ....
02/04/2016 to 20160402 ....
```

Comment: many [duplicates](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbatch-file%5D+get+yesterdays+date) available

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Batch File - getting yesterdays date and applying in current batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28767114/batch-file-getting-yesterdays-date-and-applying-in-current-batch-file)

Comment: Sorry guys but i am pretty new to batch and they all look pretty complex to me.... I thought it would be as simple as doing "%DATE% -1" but it doesnt look this easy....Also they dont show the conversion to YYYYMMDD format.

Comment: I recommend a look at http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-getdate.html and http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-datemath.html. Of course, they _are_ complex, there is no easy way in batch files. However, these ones are easy to use.

Comment: Thanks @Melebius.... Thats right, guess with batch script it does get a bit complicated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with a little help from powershell:

```
@echo off
for /l %%d in (0,1,4) do (
    for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('powershell get-date -date $(get-date^).adddays(-%%d^) -format yyyyMMdd') do set _Date%%d=%%i
) 
set _date
```

Explanation (copied word by word from TessellatingHeckler's comment - couldn't formulate it better):

> for /L is a batch file loop which counts numbers, 1 2 3 4, and each
>   time through it calls PowerShell script engine with a for /f command
>   which is a bit of a batch file workaround. The PowerShell command gets
>   the current date, adds -X days to it, then gets the resulting date,
>   and formats it in the way you want and returns it to the batch file,
>   which gets one line of text back, and uses that in the do section to
>   set the environment variable. tokens=* tells the loop not to split the
>   line of text up, and the ^ are to escape special characters in batch
>   files

`for /l` works like this: `for /l %%i in (<start>, <step>, <end>)`. In other languages it would read something like `FOR i=<start> TO <end> STEP <step>`

The powershell command assembles like this:

`get-date` - get today's date.

`get-date -date <some date>` get the date of `<some date>` (seems absurd, but in fact means "take the string `<some date>` and convert it to a valid date").

Now replace `<some date>` with `$(get-date).adddays(x)` - which means "take today, and add `x` days"

last step is formatting the resulting date to the desired format with `-format <formatstring>`

you can read powershell's help from `cmd` with `powershell get-help get-date` or more detailed: `powershell Get-Help Get-Date -Online`

Comment: You are a genius @Stephan..... !!! Thanks a lot!!.... Would you mind explaining this script a bit?

Comment: Thanks @TessellatingHeckler, i have got few questions i.e if you dont mind answering them here?

Comment: @irish Ask, but the answer is probably "it's a bodge because batch files are extremely limited and doing interesting things needs a workaround inside a workaround".

Comment: Yeah i understand that. My question is more about the script itself.                             a) for /l %%d in (0,1,4) ----- is this storing values mentioned in there into variable d? If not, what does it mean when you go for /f or for /l %%variable                                                                                                                            ------- b) powershell get-date -date $(get-date^) ----- here i understand that get-date is getting the current date what does "-date $(get-date^)" do ?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler great explanation. I copied it to my answer.

Comment: Thanks @Stephan for further explanation :) !!

Comment: @irish `for` is overloaded quite a lot - open cmd.exe and run `for /?` to see what other loop options it has.