# Batch-rename to predict a specific day of the week

Tags: batch-file, date-formatting

I'm using a batch file to rename some files every week in a month, like this:

```
@echo off

setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a" 
set "td.YY=%dt:~2,2%" 
set "td.YYYY=%dt:~0,4%"
set "td.MM=%dt:~4,2%"
set "td.DD=%dt:~6,2%"

rem Remove padding from date elements and increase day
set /a "y=%td.YYYY%", "m=100%td.MM% %% 100", "d=(100%td.DD% %% 100)+1" 
rem Calculate month length
set /a "ml=30+((m+m/8) %% 2)" & if %m% equ 2 set /a "ml=ml-2+(3-y %% 4)/3-(99-y %% 100)/99+(399-y %% 400)/399"
rem Adjust day / month / year for tomorrow date
if %d% gtr %ml% set /a "d=1", "m=(m %% 12)+1", "y+=(%m%/12)"

rem Pad date elements and set tomorrow variables
set /a "m+=100", "d+=100"

set "tm.YYYY=%y%"
set "tm.YY=%y:~-2%"
set "tm.MM=%m:~-2%"
set "tm.DD=%d:~-2%"

echo Today   : %td.YYYY%-%td.MM%-%td.DD%
echo Tomorrow: %tm.YYYY%-%tm.MM%-%tm.DD%
```

This code works very well for me so I can use it to rename my files with a date like "today" (2022-02-17) or "tomorrow" (2022-02-18), but I need to predict all days of the week like 2022-02-19, 2022-02-20 and so on..

How can I improve this code?

Comment: What do you mean by "predict"?  Are "today" and "tomorrow" used like output, as above, or as input to another script?  That is, do you want this script to output seven days starting at 2022-02-17 as "Today: 2022-02-17", "Tomorrow: 2022-02-18", "Saturday: 2022-02-19", "Sunday: 2022-02-20", etc.?  Or do you want however you're renaming files to accept "friendly" dates like "today" and "tomorrow", day names for the upcoming week, and `yyyy-MM-dd` format?

Comment: probably a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36442944/how-to-get-current-date-1-2-3-4-in-batch)

Comment: The first you said! I need to output seven days starting from launching the script. For example: today is 18/02/2022? Perfect! My script (%td.YYYY%-%td.MM%-%td.DD%) can output this date 2022-02-18 or this date (%tm.YYYY%-%tm.MM%-%tm.DD%): 2022-02-19. I need another code to output 2022-02-20, 2022-02-21, 2022-02-22, 2022-02-23 and 2022-02-24

Comment: @Guiseppe: was the link I provided yesterday helpful? It transfers date-math (which `cmd` can't do on its own; just look at the messy code to do such a simple thing as add or subtract a day) to Powershell (which comfortly can and is preinstalled on all current Windows versions). The answer there should be easy to adapt to your needs.

Comment: Hi there! Sorry @Stephan if I took a long time to reply but today, I was able to complete the necessary changes to achieve the desired result. I did it as follows:

[`@echo off
for /l %%d in (0,1,7) do (
    for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('powershell get-date -date $(get-date^).adddays(%%d^) -format yyyy-MM-dd') do set _Date%%d=%%i
) 

set _date

echo %_DATE0%
echo %_DATE1%
echo %_DATE2%
echo %_DATE3%
echo %_DATE4%
echo %_DATE5%
echo %_DATE6%
echo %_DATE7%
` ]

thanks everyone for Your help!

Comment: That looks good. You may want to turn that into a formal answer and accept it to remove the question from the "unsolved" queue, or just close it as a duplicate.