# Adding a textfile with a name to each directory

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm having some trouble with trying to add a text file to each directory in this directory having a certain name. I have a directory called `Daily Notes` where I save my notes for the day and I have this further organized by week. So I have a bunch of directories in here such as `6.5.17-6.10.17` and in each of these I need a text file with the name format such as `6.7.17DailyNotes.txt`. I know I can easily do this by hand each day, but I have some free time and am trying to learn how to program with cmd. I tried to just make a test text file with a for loop but it saved it to the directory containing the batch file. Here is my code right now:

```
@echo off
setlocal disabledelayedexpansion

set "folder=%~1"
if not defined folder set "folder=%cd%"

for /D %%a in ("%folder%\*") do (
    echo test > test.txt
)

endlocal
```

So, I want to go into each directory and make 5 text files, one for each day with the format month.day.yearDailyNotes.txt. I was thinking I could just make a variable from reading the directory name and count up in days from that for the text files. Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comment

> I know it would be very difficult to handle month changes in the
>   middle of the week, I was thinking it will be acceptable to just
>   handle that part manually, so have a file named something like
>   10.32.17DailyNotes.txt which I manually will change after

makes it much easier (Date/Time Math in Batch is [possible, but ugly and involves a lot of code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28769043/2152082))

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
REM next two lines for simulating your environment:
set "folder=%~dp0"
md 6.5.17-6.10.17 6.11.17-6.16.17 2>nul

REM for every folder
for /d %%f in ("%folder%*.*.*-*.*.*") do (
  REM extract day, month and year [from first part of foldername]
  for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=.-" %%a in ("%%~nxf")do (
    REM calculate "end day" [may be greater than days in that month]
    set /a end=%%b+5
    REM for [start] to [end]
    for /l %%i in (%%b,1,!end!) do (
      REM create blank file
      break > "%%f\%%a.%%i.%%cDailyNotes.txt"
    )
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over all of the subdirectories and create a test.txt file.

```
set "folder=%~1"
if not defined folder set "folder=%cd%"

FOR /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%a IN (`DIR /S /B /A:D "%folder%\*"`) DO (
    ECHO test > "%%~a\test.txt"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal disabledelayedexpansion

set "folder=%~1"
if not defined folder set "folder=%cd%"

for /D %%q in ("%folder%\*") do (
    echo test "%%q\%%~nxqDailyNotes.txt"
)

ENDLOCAL
```

Interesting exercise with a couple of twists.

my posted code will simply show 'test "*fullfilename*" '. Naturally, you could use `copy nul "*fullfilename*"' to create an empty file (with`>nul`to suppress the creation-report) or`echo.>"*fullfilename*"` to create a file containing just an empty line - or whatever.

The main magic is with the gymnastics in creating the filename. Since you are using `for/d`, the directoryname will appear in `%%q`. so the required filename is the name+extension part of that directoryname (you and I know it's actually not a filename but the outermost leafname of a directory tree - just don't tell `cmd`) so we use `%%~nxq` meaning the name and extension part of the "filename" in `%%q` (see `for /?|more` from the prompt for documentation). We then just tack the remainder of the required name on as a literal.

So - why the change to `%%q`?

Suppose we leave it as `%%a`. The filename would then be "%%~nxaDailyNotes.txt" and be interpreted as name,extension,attribute,drive of `%%a` since `i` is neither a modifier nor a participating metavariable. Changing the metavariable from `%%a` to `%%q` removes the misinterpretation.

Comment: I'm afraid, OP expects six textfiles for the folder `6.5.17-6.10.17`: `06.05.17DailyNotes.txt`, `06.06.17DailyNotes.txt`, `06.07.17DailyNotes.txt`, `06.08.17DailyNotes.txt`, `06.09.17DailyNotes.txt` and `06.10.17DailyNotes.txt`. Will be difficult, when a month change happens during the week. @greenthumptack: May `MonDailyNotes`, `TueDailyNotes`,... be an acceptable alternative?

Comment: I would prefer it to be the dates of the week. I know it would be very difficult to handle month changes in the middle of the week, I was thinking it will be acceptable to just handle that part manually, so have a file named something like `10.32.17DailyNotes.txt` which I manually will change after since there will only be a few cases of these.

Comment: @Stephan: My interpretation of the problem is that one file is required to be created in the existing directories `6.5.17-6.10.17` (6 directories) and the filename to be *the same name as the directory*+"DailyNotes.txt". I can see no logical reason for wanting a set of 6 files (not 5 - fencepost error) named with the days of the entire week in **each** directory. What seems logical to me however may not be what's logical for OP. Really - is it required that (a number of) files, one for each day of the week is installed in *each* of the existing directories for the week?